# Maior valor num vetor fixo de 10 posições

Tags: c, array

Estou com exercício pendente para encontra o maior elemento em um vetor fixo de 10 elementos. 
Porém, quando declaro os inteiro do vetor funciona, mas quando peço para o usuário entra com os valores não funciona.

```
int i, v[10];
int maior = v[0];
for(i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    if(maior < v[i])
        maior = v[i];
}
printf("Maior = %d\n", maior);
```

Comment: Seria porque está usando o operador de menor para verificar se é maior?

Comment: Para o que está a tentar fazer não precisa do array, e acaba por ser o motivo pelo qual não funciona

Comment: vi isso agora mesmo, mas minha duvida é porque eu inicializando a matriz com os valores de entradas da certo ao mostra o maior ?

Comment: pra mim era pra funcionar,  inicializando maior com o primeiro elemento do vetor e testa assim por diante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está a enviar o valor de `v[0]` para a variável `maior`, sem sequer definir algum valor para ele, logo vai um valor que não consegue controlar.

*Imagine que `v[0]` tem o valor de `403234`, ao escrever valores menores que esse valor no `scanf` nunca irá alterar `maior`, logo no fim irá dar print desse numero.*

Poderia usar colocar na variável `maior` o valor de -1, caso apenas lê-se numeros positivos, mas não seria a melhor opção também.

---

Pode fazer do seguinte modo:

```
int i, v[10];
int maior;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    if(i==0)
        maior=v[i];
    else if(maior < v[i])
        maior = v[i];
}
printf("Maior = %d\n", maior);
```